# How to show historical data in Wirecloud?

Tags: fiware-wirecloud

I would like to show through Wirecloud some sensor´s historical data that I have stored in a Cosmos instance from Orion. The data is stored in a HDFS table.

Looking through the options, I chose the operator **History Module to Linear Graph** and the widget **Linear Graph**. Please let me know if there are others better suited for this.

The **History Module to Linear Graph** requests a *HistoryMod Server URL*, should I give the Cosmos url? I get an error when trying to open the widget documentation, so I don´t know how to proceed.

I saw that in the Santander example something similar was accomplished through CKAN, using the **CKAN Resource Selector** and **Data Viewer Table** widgets. Is this the only way to show historical data in Wirecloud (using CKAN)?